# Maven and open Km build failure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I am facing this issue when I am deploying my openkm application using Maven:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.316 sError log,
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-15T09:31:54+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-cli) on project openkm: GWT Module com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.Crypto not found in project sources or resources. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: your relative content from pom please

Comment: Ok i will edit my Question

Comment: i can not edit my question is too long

Comment: Does your pom include `<groupId>com.googlecode.gwt-crypto</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-crypto</artifactId>` as a dependency from any source?

Comment: this group id is not found in my pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.Crypto not found in project sources

Please make sure your dependencies include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.gwt-crypto</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-crypto</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```